# Facebook Graph API: Get likes from user/likes after specified time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an Android app which has a requirement of keeping track of a user's interests in a local DB. The idea is to source the "interests" as "pages liked by a user on Facebook (and their associated categories)".

Graph API Endpoint: `/me/likes`

Parameters: `fields=id,name,category,category_list,created_time`

The problem I am facing is while updating the list of interests periodically, I am unable to retrieve **only the new pages liked** since the last time we hit the API.

I have tried using the `since` parameter but it doesn't seem to work. (I think the `/likes` edge is cursor paginated and not considered a time-series -like `/posts` or `/feed`, for example). However, the page node does have `created_time` field which indicates when the user liked the page.

**TLDR;**
How to get all liked pages from `/me/likes` endpoint after a specified date-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to use pagination to get all entries, and detect new ones on your own by comparing them with your database entries. But you don´t need to check on your own, that´s what the Realtime API is for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

Debug the result, maybe you even get the new likes directly in the API response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already have pagination in place to get all the likes. I guess I will have to do the brute force method of getting all the likes and filtering out the old ones client side.. The real-time API needs server side configuration to set up a callback url which I unfortunately don't control :(